# Why IDEA doesn't suspend on breakpoints?

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

I'm developing Spring application on Groovy. Some of my breakpoints are skipped by IDEA, some of them are not. Check the screens... May be you have some ideas about it. I created a question because it's not the first time I meet this problem

skipped:
[image]

not skipped:
[image]

As you can see on the screens I have method `restoreJobState`. I expect code to be suspended before `restoreJobState` call (first screen) and then inside `restoreJobState` (second screen). But IDEA skips first one

Comment: What breakpoint suspend policy did you set?

Comment: 11.0 Build 111.69, Suspend policy = "All" (everything by default)

Comment: Looks like can be caused by the same Groovy bug as http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-82741

Comment: This bug was fixed in 1.8.7 version. I'm using 1.8.8